# Why does my recursive for loop keep repeating the first item in the list?

Tags: bash, for-loop, recursion

I am using a recursive for loop and it repeatedly keeps repeating the command for the first directory in the list instead of moving to the next one. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch bm4ranks.table
tmp_file=$(mktemp /tmp/file.XXX)
function recursive_for_loop {
for f in *;  do
    if [ -d $f  -a ! -h $f ];
    then
        cd $f;
        cd output.$f;
        touch tmp.$f;
        head -11 $f.bm4ranks | cut -c 22-28 > tmp.$f;
        TMPTOPTEN=$(awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' tmp.$f | cut -c 1-3,5-7 | paste -s)
        echo $TMPTOPTEN > tmp.$f
        mv tmp.$f ..
        cd ..
        mv tmp.$f ..
        cd ..
        TOPTEN=$(cat tmp.$f)
        echo "$f $TOPTEN" >> bm4ranks.table
        echo Done Transferring Top Ten for $f
        PID="$!"
        echo "$PID:$f" >> $tmp_file
        PID_LIST+="$PID "
        # use recursion to navigate the entire tree
        recursive_for_loop;
        cd ..;
     fi;
done;
};
recursive_for_loop
```

I have a directory of folders that have an output subfolder unique to each folder. I am extracting the first 11 lines, cutting some parts, merging the two fields that are left and then pasting these values as a row instead of a column into a file called bm4ranks.table. I know my commands work as when I run it, I get the output I want in my bm4ranks.table, but the problem is that it keeps pasting the same set of ranks over and over again instead of going through the list of directories and terminating. Why does it do this?

Comment: You need to include a [mre], not your entire program.

Comment: This might help: [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not catching your objective but you call your function from the directory where you started first (Two times cd "into s.th.", two times cd..). So you are doing the same over and over again. Recursion would be helpful if you have nested folders with output folders.

Comment: so where should i call the function? what in the function tells the commands to move on to the next folder?

Comment: My first try would be before the 2nd "cd .." - but you have to rearrange some of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the directories you are in at various points in the function.

- you start at some basic directory, let's say `~`
- the line `cd $f;` takes you into a subdirectory, let's say `~/dir1`
- the line `cd output.$f;` takes you into `~/dir1/output.dir1`
- after various commands, you do `cd ..` so you're back in `~/dir1`
- two lines after that comes another `cd ..` so you're back in `~`

So when you recurse back into the same function, you are in the same directory where you started. The function will again do `for f in *;` with the exact same result as the previous time, and the first thing on that list will be `dir1` again.

Most likely you simply have one too many `cd ..` in your function. If you remove one of them, the recursion will happen in a subdirectory, which is probably what you're trying to do.